# Firebase.js: Authentication doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to print `Success` on the console whenever the user enters the right email/password. I have entered a false info and it works, but with a correct user the console nor logs the success or appends to the `errors` div

```
 document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (error) {
                console.log(error.message)
                  $("#errors").append('   <br><div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert> <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a> <p>'+ error.message + '</p></div>       <br>');

            }
              $("#errors").append('   <br><div class="uk-alert-success" uk-alert> <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a> <p>Login Success, Welcome</p></div>       <br>');
              console.log("success")


         });
 });
```

Could anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you try to detect a success in the `catch()` method.

Since the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) method returns a Promise you should use the `then()` method as follows:

```
 document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
             .then(function(userCredential) {
                    console.log(userCredential.user);
                    $("#errors").append('   <br><div class="uk-alert-success" uk-alert> <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a> <p>Login Success, Welcome</p></div>       <br>');
                    console.log("success")
             })
             .catch(function(error) {
             // Handle Errors here.
               var errorCode = error.code;
               var errorMessage = error.message;

               // if (error) { // Not needed anymore
                   console.log(error.message)
                    $("#errors").append('   <br><div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert> <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a> <p>'+ error.message + '</p></div>       <br>');


         });
 });
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you <3

Comment: @excitedmicrobe Thanks! :-)